# Find the ratio of the area of the original triangle to the area of the equilateral triangle at Gergonne point

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

If $G$ is the Gergonne point of $\triangle PQR$ and $A, D, E$ are the contact points of the incircle such that $\triangle PGE$ is equilateral. What is the ratio of area $\dfrac{\triangle PQR}{\triangle PGE}$?

[image]

**My attempt:**

Let's put this in $X$-$Y$ coordinates with $C$ as origin and line $PQ$ being parallel to the $X$-axis and $EC$ being the $Y$-axis ($C$ is the center of the incircle and radius $r$).

$\angle APQ = \angle PER = \alpha = 60^0$; Say, $PG = EG = PE = 1$ unit

Coordinates of points: $E(0,-r), P(-1,-r), C(0,0)$.

The equation of the line $PR$: $y + r = m(x+1)$

As line $PR$ is tangent to the circle, the perpendicular from center $C$ will be equal to the radius.

$r = \dfrac{r - m}{\sqrt{m^2+1}}$ or, $m = \dfrac{2r}{1-r^2}$

So, the equation of the line $PR$: $y + r = \dfrac{2r}{1-r^2} (x+1)$ ...(1)

Equation of line $ER$:  $y + r = -x \tan\alpha$ ...(2)

Equating (1) and (2), we get the intersection point $R (x_0,y_0)$

[$\dfrac{-2r}{2r+(1-r^2)\tan \alpha}, \dfrac{2r\tan \alpha}{2r+(1-r^2)\tan \alpha} - r$], where $\tan \alpha = \tan 60^0 = \sqrt3$

Equation of line $QR$:

$y - y_0 = m_0 (x - x_0)$

Again equating perpendicular distance from the center and the radius

$r = \dfrac{m_0x_0 - y_0}{\sqrt{m_0^2+1}}$

or, $(x_0^2-r^2)m_0^2 - 2x_0y_0m_0 + (y_0^2 - r^2) = 0$

As there are two lines passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ that are tangent to the circle ($PR$ and $QR$), the quadratic equation will give us two values of $m_0$, one of them being $m_0 = \dfrac{2r}{1-r^2}$ as we have established before.

**This is how far I reached. I tried to replace values of ($x_0, y_0$) in the quadratic equation and we already know one of the roots but it is becoming very tedious to find the slope of line $QR$.**

Once I know the slope, I can find the point $A$ and as we know the equation of line $PA$, I should be able to find the value of $r$ as well as coordinates of points $P, Q, R$. That will lead to us finding the area of $\triangle PQR$ and the ratio to $\triangle PGE$ (area of $\triangle PGE = \dfrac {\sqrt3}{4}$ units).

**Any suggestions on how to simplify the solution? Are there any known properties of gergonne point that I am missing which makes the solution simpler?**

Comment: haven't you considered using barycentrical coordinates ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I did go ahead and solve with the help of mathematica at that point. While I have used barycentric coordinates to a limited extent in the past (to find center of a circle in 3D space etc.), it did not occur to me that it could make things easier in this case.

Comment: The barycentric coordinates of P,G,E are easy to find. Computing their $3\times3$ determinant (giving the ratio area(PGE)/area(ABC)) is immediate. What remains to do is to express that $PGE$ is equilateral.

Comment: you mean ratio of area $(PGE)$ / area $(PQR)$?  I do not understand when you say what remains is to express that PGE is equilateral. That is already given.

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) As barycentric coordinates are affine whereas condition of "equilaterality" is metric, the latter generates a "constraint"...

Comment: Yes make sense. I will definitely have to do some study to solve using barycentric coordinates. It has been a long long time :)

Comment: Several times, I have found barycentrical coordinates useful. The last time I used them was a month ago for [this issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3852723) that I found difficult as well as very interesting ; besides, if you have any idea...

Comment: @JeanMarie there is an answer which uses an easier approach (for calculations) than what I had embarked upon. Given you had commented earlier on this, thought you may be interested in it.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate this kind of cross-information. About triangle centers like Gergonne point, and more generally about triangle geometry, you will perhaps be interested but the answer I wrote recently in an "historical" perspective [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4254494).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\begin{array}{} λ(C,r) & ω(P,1) & C=(0,0) \\ P=(-1,-r) & E=(0,-r)  \\ \text{ΔPGE is equilateral} & PG=EG=EP=1 & G=(\frac{-1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-r) \\ \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} λ∩ω=D & PG∩λ=A & DG∩PE=Q \\ AQ⟂AC & m_{AQ}·m_{AC}=-1 & PD∩EG=R \\ x^2+y^2=r^2 & (x+1)^2+(y+r)^2=1 & x+r·y+r^2=0 \\ \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} y=\frac{-(x+r^2)}{r} & D=\left( \frac{-2r^2}{r^2+1},\frac{r(1-r^2)}{r^2+1}  \right)   \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} PG∩λ=A & \left| \begin{array}{} x & y & 1 \\ -1 & -r & 1 \\ \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-r & 1 \\ \end{array} \right|=0  & y=x·\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{3}-r & x^2+y^2=r^2 \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} x_{A}=\frac{1}{4}\left( \sqrt{3r^2+2\sqrt{3}r-3}+\sqrt{3}r-3  \right)  & y_{A}=x_{A}·\sqrt{3+\sqrt{3}-r}  \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} x_{Q}=\frac{2r}{\sqrt{3}-r} & y_{Q}=-r  \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} m_{AQ}·m_{AC}=-1 & ⇒ & -\sqrt{3r^2+2r\sqrt{3}-3}+3r^2-9+(\sqrt{3r^2+2r\sqrt{3}-3})\sqrt{3}r)=0 & ⇒ \\ r=\frac{7\sqrt{3}}{9}≈1.3471506  \\ \end{array}$

$ratio=\frac{ΔPQR}{ΔPGE}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left| \begin{array}{} -1 & \frac{7\sqrt{3}}{9} & 1 \\ 7 & \frac{-7\sqrt{3}}{9} & 1 \\ \frac{-21}{10} & \frac{119\sqrt{3}}{90} & 1 \\ \end{array} \right| }{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}}=\frac{168}{5}=33.6$

[image: Georgone]