# Any type of operator not unary or binary?

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

I'm studying the Cartesian product, which is bound to the idea of a binary relation. Even with Cartesian products of several sets, n-ary Cartesian products, we have to think combinatorically as two sets at a time, recursively. Is there any sort of operation where there is, say, a triary operation happening. Obviously, when we have $3 - 2 - 1$ we have to think of associative rules, forcing subtraction to be a binary operator "step-through" affair. There is no $3 \oplus 2 \oplus 1$ operator that does something in one fell swoop to all three numbers is there? Lisp has `(+ 1 2 3)` and grade-school math has vertical addition with the plus-sign and a line under the lowest number, but these are not "internally" non-binary. The only thing that takes "three at once" is, yes, a product-based operator, again, an n-ary Cartesian product. Correct? Another example would be playing poker and being dealt five cards. The cards were shuffled, which is a combinatoric  permutation of the stack of cards, which are then dealt into hands. Is there anything from probability (or anywhere) that doesn't start with a shuffle permutation therefore binary, rather, just looks at the five cards coming together non-permutation-, non-binary-wise?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132028/discussion-on-question-by-147pm-any-type-of-operator-not-unary-or-binary).

Comment: If you're willing to consider *partial* functions the various [triangle centers](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/rocky-mountain-journal-of-mathematics/volume-23/issue-4/Triangle-Centers-as-Functions/10.1216/rmjm/1181072493.full) provide many interesting ternary functions which don't in any sense come from binary functions in a natural way. For example, the orthocenter function "almost always" satisfies $$\mathsf{orth}(\mathsf{orth}(A,B,C),B,C)=A,$$ a phenomenon which seems to be rare *([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4281644/), [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/407981/))*.

Comment: On the other hand, if you interpret things sufficiently broadly, *every* finite-arity operation is reducible to a combination of binary ones: e.g. a ternary function $$f:X^3\rightarrow Y$$ can be thought of as the binary function $$(X^2\times X)\rightarrow X: ((a,b),c)\mapsto f(a,b,c).$$ But note that this requires us to "modify" the domain: when looking at structures which don't admit a "reasonably definable" pairing function, this trick doesn't work and there will in general be many natural essentially-high-arity operations.

Answer (score 1):

How about a $3$-number average? (Or more numbers if you want an operator that takes more than $3$ arguments.)  You don't get the correct value by averaging the first two numbers and then averaging that result with the third.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But you relied on addition which is binary left-right-associative. Anything other ideas?